Upstairs AC runs constantly. Air smells moist
My 2-story home, 5000 sq ft, was built in 2000. The upstairs AC constantly runs and the humidity is around 65%. AC is 6 years old and it gets regular maintenance every quarter.
The return vent is in the same closet as the AC handler. Over the years, the unit has flooded several times. Pipes are cleared.  I can't help but wonder if the return vent should be relocated? The fan gets gunked up with black soot-type material.
This is my 3rd Air conditioner for this area. Also, the roof is new, no leaks. Thank you.

It sound as if your unit is in an area of high humidity.  It may need a dehumidifier.  Please look at your question again, some details are questionable.  Your home is 4 years old, but the AC is 6 years old and it has been replaced twice?  Make and model of the AC would help as well.

Hello. the house was built in 2000. Typo! Thanks for catching that

I am confused, are you saying the upstairs ac unit is or has flooded? Does that mean the upstairs AC unit is located downstairs or in a basement? Is the fan getting "guncked up" the interior fan or the exterior fan? and where on earth are you located?

Does the utility closet back up to a bathroom?   I had a small leak in a shower that had an air handler in a closet opposite that wall.  My Ac sucked in a lot of humidity from the  bathroom particularly the shower.   When I remodeled the bath I cured the AC issue by removing the moisture from the shower leak.
